# how to save the generated xml file using jsp?

Tags: html, xml, jsp

i have generated xml file using jsp,but i want the generated xml file should be saved as a file.
my code is

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <%@ page contentType="text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1" %>
   <playlist version="1" xmlns = "http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
   <title>My Band Rocks Your Socks</title>
   <trackList>
   <%! String[] sports; %>
   <%
    sports = request.getParameterValues("sports");
    if (sports != null)
    { 
         for (int i = 0; i < sports.length; i++)
         { 
              // out.println (sports[i]); 
              String total=sports[i];
              String[] sa=total.split("[,]");
              // String[] sub=new String();
              out.print("<track>");
              for (int j=0;j<sa.length;j++)
              {
                // out.println(sa[j]);
                // out.println("sa["+j+"]="+sa[j]);
                if( j == 0)
                {
                     out.print("<location>" + sa[0] +"</location>"); 
                }
                else if (j == 1)
                     {
                        out.print("<image>" + sa[1] +"</image>"); 
                     }
                     else if( j==2)
                          {
                            out.print("<title>" + sa[2] +"</title>");
                          }

               }// end of inner for loop()       
               out.print("</track>");
         //out.println();
      }// end of outer for()
    } 
    //else out.println ("<b>none<b>");
  %>
  </trackList>
 </playlist>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. The way to do it is basically to set an extra header - which you can do on the response object.

The header to set is called Content-Disposition and the value should be something like "attachment; filename=\"foo.xml\"".

Comment: hi Bini,
I added <% response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"playlist.xml\""); %> worked fine but it is
 prompting to save the file in a particular location..
cant i directly have a code to directly store it in one location and overwrite the same file in the next run.

Comment: @musicking123: You can't force things onto the client machine. You can specify the filename and MIME type but that's it. From there is the browser taking over and user's choice on what to do with it.